# C++ error al imprimir los registros guardados en un archivo binario

Tags: c++, archivo, binario

Se me pide guardar registros en un archivo binario con dos campos de tipo string usando estructuras ,para ello cree dos funciones una para escribir los registros en el archivo y otra para leerlos pero el problema es que al grabar los registros solo se me almacena el ultimo registro que introduzco lo se por que al abrir el archivo con el block de notas puedo ver solo el ultimo dato amacenado junto a otros caracteres y el tamaño de archivo no concuerda con el numero de registros que introduzco, tambien al leer los datos me sale un ciclo infinito con caracteres que nada tienen que ver con los registros, como puedo arreglar esto?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

struct per{
  string nom;
  string mas;
};

FILE *a;
void add_arch(string b,string c){
   a=fopen("Prueba.dat","wb");
    if (a == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nError al abrir archivo\n");
    }
   struct per persona1 ={b,c};
   fwrite(&persona1,sizeof(struct per),1,a);
   fclose(a);
}

void leer_arch(){
   a=fopen("Prueba.dat","rb");
   if (a == NULL)
   {
        printf("\nError al abrir archivo\n");
   }
   struct per aux;
   while(!feof(a)){
      fread(&aux,sizeof(per),1,a);
      printf("%s %s\n",aux.nom,aux.mas);
      fseek(a,sizeof(per),SEEK_CUR);
   }
   fclose(a);
}

int main()
{
    add_arch("gabriel","gato");
    add_arch("gabriel2","gato2");
    add_arch("gabriel3","gato3");
    add_arch("gabriel4","gato4");
    add_arch("gabriel5","gato5");
    leer_arch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> al grabar los registros solo se me almacena el ultimo registro

Es normal, pues [al abrir el archivo sobrescribes el contenido anterior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen):

```
fopen("Prueba.dat","wb");
```

| Cadena | Significado | Explicación | Si el archivo existe... | Si el archivo no existe... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "r" | leer | Abrir para lectura | Lectura desde el inicio | Error |
| "w" | escribir | Crea un archivo para escritura | **Destruye contenido** | Crea el archivo |
| "a" | anexar | Anexa a un archivo | Escribir al final | Crea el archivo |
| "r+" | lectura extendida | Abrir un archivo para lectura/escritura | Lectura desde el inicio | Error |
| "w+" | escritura extendida | Crear un archivo para lectura/escritura | Destruye el contenido | Crea el archivo |
| "a+" | anexar extendido | Abrir un archivo para lectura/escritura | Escribir al final | Crea el archivo |

Respecto a tu segundo problema:

> al leer los datos me sale un ciclo infinito

Diré que tiene que ver con que usas `fseek` sin necesidad de ello, no entraré en detalles porque tienes que rehacer todo el código ya que lo has hecho mal:

- Has etiquetado la pregunta como [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) pero estás programando en [c](/questions/tagged/c):

  - En C++ la escritura en archivos se hace con `std::ofstream` y la lectura con `std::ifstream`, ambos objetos de la cabecera `<fstream>`.
  - En C++ la escritura en consola se hace con `std::cout`, de la cabecera `<iostream>`.
  - En C++ las estructuras (`struct`) son tipos fundamentales, no necesitas anteponer `struct` para hacer referencia a ellas.
  - Las cabeceras `<stdio.h>` y `<stdlib.h>` son de C, en C++ no deben usarse.
  - Los objetos `std::string` pertenecen a la cabecera `<string>`, la cuál no has incluido.
- Las variables deben tener nombres auto-explicativos, variables con nombres como `a`, `b`, y `c` no dan ninguna pista de para qué sirven.

Tu código, si estuviese programado en C++ [podría parecerse a](https://tio.run/##lVJNi9swED1bv2JwYdeBdLf04xIH39pSKKXQHnNR5Ek6IM8YSV4WlvyY/pb@sHSU2Mmm28PuwWj83uPNzJNc37923vJ2v39F7PzQIixJYgpou8acsc1TSBHibWPMEPUEth3G3jqEmNraGKUHl6DH8GCKoxZYuvr009lYm50qx3ZwJSq2ScJyWZ2xOTjheDCCq35m1C1gGgKDwHIJ/Y2a5uJ6xddHQI0nQBsYQ//6N011wmj@2FlHXyy2mDwxVpnK7rP6f4R2ycQ4Cx07cdK1iKuD2e0tfBNgdBgp6UydtAJrYhtIFoAx/fkd9XCB1oSsXML7JKagDVQyBg42uF90Jw/l9zDg2t60NpW7mSnUvxg5rYq8uCZdfrZhQ@jbcq5lknL3mPwSqZUgIwdvL9kf5O8wd534d5f8J/R0P3HvL7mf0k3Mh3J3Tr9QFfqIqnUypEyUK/4YggSwHjQv5GTDlIIWDOinpVdc6vM45EHPyWOjrlW@Tf2isK0nNTTNGZvlwQ/3eRrpK2owCyjhuE/WvXwHj9r5yfDj@3ij72O//ws):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct per{
    string nom;
    string mas;
};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &o, const per &p)
{
    return o << p.nom << '\n' << p.mas << '\n';
}

istream &operator>>(istream &i, per &p)
{
    std::getline(i, p.nom);
    std::getline(i, p.mas);
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    // No necesitas modo binario: estás escribiendo texto
    if (ofstream archivo{"Prueba.dat"})
    {
        archivo
            << per{"Garfield","Gato"}
            << per{"Isidoro","Gato 2"}
            << per{"Silvestre","Gato 3"}
            << per{"Felix","Gato 4"}
            << per{"Tom","Gato 5"} << '\n';
    }
    else
        cout << "\nError al intentar escribir en el archivo\n";

    if (ifstream archivo{"Prueba.dat"})
    {
        for (per persona; archivo >> persona; )
            std::cout << "Leido: " << persona << '\n';
    }
    else
        cout << "\nError al intentar leer el archivo\n";

    return 0;
}
```